# Silent type conversions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just recently discovered that SQL Server will return equivalent answers for the following two queries

```
select * from myTable
    where column1 in('034','023')

select * from myTable
    where column1 in (34,23)
```

The data type in the varchar.  Does anyone have a link or knowledge of other 'silent' datatype conversions in SQL Server (or T-SQL, specifically perhaps)

Comment: That would be the implicit data type conversion. Have a look here [Data Type Conversion (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: And here [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Those will only be equivalent if column is a numeric (e.g. int) type. If column1 were varchar and a record has '34' for column1, it would fail to pass the where class in the first query, though it would pass in the second. This may be what @veljasije was asking about.

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, I exactly asked because I suppose that there was done implicit conversion. Thank you for finishing my thought

Answer (score 0):

See the linked MSDN article on implicit and explicit conversions.  Partway down the page, there is a grid with visual indicators of the conversions available between the data types in MS SQL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx